# Magento 2.2.5: When deploying not coping css to pub/static

Tags: magento2, magento-2.2.5, static-content-deploy

I have a Magento 2.2.5 based website and when I do a below command:

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
and then
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

And then I look in the

```
pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/css
```

And the same CSS file that is in

```
app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/web/css
```

Is not copied over to the pub static folder?
I checked and the Magento mode is production. Also I made sure the pub static is writable. I also tried renaming the static folder to 'static---' and then recompiled and redeployed and again the CSS file for some reason was not there in pub static?

Comment: Did you not deleted .htaccess in pub/static/.htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download .htaccess from official Magento 2 repository

Run below command.

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Never delete .htaccess file from pub/static

Answer (score 0):

**Try below command step by step and check again.**

> Step 1) Add .htaccess file from native Magento 2 source.
>
> Step 2) php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> Step 3) php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
>
> Step 4) php bin/magento cache:flush

**Note:** Do not delete .htaccess file from pub/static

Hope it help!